# Redirect loop error on freshly installed CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I tried to autoload session on codeigniter then i got this redirect loop error

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

this is the only code i added on the autoload file

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: This webpage has a redirect loop


The webpage at http://thissite.com/ has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
Learn more about this problem.
Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 0):

So  i finally find the problem on this its you have to disable or enable mod_security under your server depending on your requirements needed